# Sublime text 2 plugin for Salesforce

Tags: developer-productivity

i'have installed **Sublime Text 2** and i want to start to code with this for Salesforce development.

I'm using Windows.

Do you know which is the best plugin?

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Mavensmate is awesome for Sublime Text 2 - not sure if there is a Windows version though

Comment: There is work in progress version for Windows, https://github.com/joeferraro/MavensMate-SublimeText/pull/53, it looks to be still WIP though.

Comment: "Best" is subjective. Its a matter of finding what works for you. Try what's available and see what feels comfortable. Many people like Sublime Text. With the proper customizations, you may find that you like it too. I use a variety of different tools depending on what I'm working on and the situation.

Answer (score 9):

MavensMate for Sublime Text now supports OSX, Windows, and Linux. The only catch is it requires Sublime Text 3.

http://mavensmate.com/Plugins/Sublime_Text/Installation#windows

Answer (score 1):

I'll be posting this at the mavensmate github repo as well, but I suspect many people will find this article so heads up:

Mavensmate for windows (beta) as of 9.19.2013 appears to have hard coded git protocols in the installation python script. Ie: git:// vs. http:// 99% of people won't experience any problems with this, but! if you find that mavensmate installed, apparently properly, but does not run, or provide the plugin -- Check to see that you can clone a git repository via the git:// protocol. Your firewall may be blocking it.

Answer (score 1):

No plugin necessary for Sublime Text 1, 2 or 3.  For Apex, I view the code with Java syntax and it works great.  For Visualforce, HTML works very well.  For formulas, Plain Text helps you keep your parentheses lined up better than editing within Salesforce.